# Timeout on Heroku for rest-client / selenium webdriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, heroku

I have a background job that runs every ten minutes, but always times out when I installed on heroku.

```
Net::ReadTimeout
```

This is the error I am getting. When I go into the heroku console, i can curl the endpoint, so Im not sure where there is a time out.

It's written in ruby. I'm not sure if I have to add a build pack to this, but I currently have

```
1. heroku/nodejs
2. https://github.com/notvad/heroku-buildpack-selenium.git
3. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome.git
4. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver.git
5. heroku/ruby
```

I have reached out to Heroku, and they tell me "they dont do code troubleshooting"

I have tried this on my local machine, as well as spinning up an EC2 Instance.

It works there out of the box

Comment: What do your logs say? (try `heroku logs --tail` to see if it's a server issue or `heroku run rails console` to see if it's a rails issue - both in the command line.) Aside from that, are you using the free version of Heroku? I think the dyno will time out ever half-hour or something, try running `heroku ps`.

Comment: No I'm paying for both an app server and a worker VM. All the log say is Net::ReadTimeout

Comment: @R.J.Robinson Did you find out what was the issue?